# memory of the USB devices in power 2?

Tags: memory-management

Why the memory of the USB devices is always in the powers of 2?

Comment: "pendrives are always in the power of 2" as in *"the capacity of* USB flash memory drives is always a power of two"?

Comment: You'll probably be taken a little more seriously in life if you learn some form of English. Or any language really :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because all memory devices are essentially an array of bytes or words. As such there is an address (index) and data which are both binary numbers. So a 1 Megabyte memory will have a 20 bit address "bus" and an 8 bit data bus. These buses are physically constructed with one electrical conductor per bit, so the 1Meg device will have 20 address pins and 8 data pins. In DRAM, there may be multiplexing, where half of the address is sent on one clock cycle and the other half on another clock cycle - this can reduce the number of physical pins and traces on a circuit board. Making a 2Meg memory out of such chips is easy, you connect the address and data pins together and then use the "chip select" pin to determine which one is being accessed via the 21st address bit. Partitioning memory in a non-power-of-2 scheme requires a LOT more circuitry and interconnection complexity to figure out which chip your data is in, and it means not using every bit combination of the address lines which all mean less efficient use of circuitry.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What a beautifully crafted answer to a truly poorly written question. +1

Answer (score 0):

Because flash memory chips are always manufactured with capacities in powers of two, as it doesn't waste address space. Because addressing is done in binary, the maximum number is always a power of two (minus 1).